# change position/orientation of a bone using assimp

Tags: c++, glsl, matrix, assimp, rigging

I have been using assimp to import rigged models and animations. I followed [this](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html) tutorial for skeletal animation and I have got it done properly. The part that I am trying to do now is to orient a certain mesh by using transformation matrix, which represents change from the initial orientation of bone For example, rotating left hand of the model by a 90 deg angle shall make the hand vertical if it's initially horizontal. To achieve this I have taken the following steps:

1. map each bone with its bone offset matrix, given by pBoneData[BoneIndex].BoneOffset below. This BoneOffset matrix transforms from mesh space to bone space.
2. find the parent bone in a mesh i.e. body part,
3. get the matrix for orienting the mesh, and save this matrix for parent bone of that mesh, given by pBoneData[BoneIndex].rotTransform. For all the other bones in a mesh, the orientation matrix is identity matrix;
4. traverse the node heirarchy and assign final transformation for each bone as:

   ```
   void rag::BoneTransform(const aiScene* mScene)
   {
   aiNode* pNode = mScene->mRootNode;
   readNode(pNode, IdentityMatrix);
   }

   //recursive process
   void rag::readNode(aiNode* pNode, Matrix4f& ParentTransform)
   {
    Matrix4f rot, GlobalTransformation;
    std::string NodeName(pNode->mName.data);
    Matrix4f NodeTransformation(pNode->mTransformation); 

    if (boneMapping.find(NodeName) != boneMapping.end())
    {
    //if node represents a bone, then take it`s unique index
    unsigned int BoneIndex = boneMapping[NodeName];
    //rot is the matrix that represents change in orientation of bone
    rot = pBoneData[BoneIndex].rotTransform;
    GlobalTransformation = ParentTransform * NodeTransformation;
    pBoneData[BoneIndex].FinalTransformation = GlobalInverseTransform * GlobalTransformation * pBoneData[BoneIndex].BoneOffset;
    }

    GlobalTransformation = ParentTransform * NodeTransformation;

   for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < pNode->mNumChildren ; i++)
   readNode(pNode->mChildren[i], GlobalTransformation);

   }
   ```

If the function above is run as it is, it will display the model in the state it was while posing it in Blender, in T pose in my case. I am having problems on using 'rot' Matrix. One of the books that I read suggested multiplying the initialBoneOrientation with the changeMatrix. My initial thoughts was to sum 'rot' with NodeTransformation as both of these represent relative change from their parent Matrices. However, I got a totally disfigured model on doing so. Any thoughts on these is highly welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The animation data provided by the assimp library is expressed as absolute values, relative to the node/bone's parent;  you just set the translation/rotation/scale specified by the animation directly on the node or bone being animated --  don't try to "combine" it with the initial orientation or any other value.

More detail in the [assimp library documentation](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/data.html)

> To apply such an animation you need to identify the animation tracks that refer to actual bones in your mesh. Then for every track:
>
> 1. Find the keys that lay right before the current anim time.
> 2. Optional: interpolate between these and the following keys.
> 3. Combine the calculated position, rotation and scaling to a tranformation matrix
> 4. Set the affected node's transformation to the calculated matrix.